# Относительный padding несужается

Tags: css

Почему при уменьшении области видимости, границы у li (зелёные) не сужаются до текста?

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  width: 70%;
}

.container,
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block {
  margin: 10px 15%;
}

.block li {
  border:1px solid green;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3.74659400544959%;/*27.5px / 700px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <ul class="">
      <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Скидки</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Вопрос</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 3.74659400544959% сами вычисляли?

Comment: да сам, а что ?

Comment: Сложно же вычислить такое :)

Comment: `padding` не становится меньше, так как он расчитывается от ширины `ul`